# Throw an exception from WebGL

Tags: webgl

Is there any way to throw a run-time exception from a WebGL shader? Since shaders are written a flavor of C which does not support exceptions, I imagine this isn't going to be easy.

I have inserted divide by zero errors but these are flagged as warnings during 'constant folding' but I don't believe that occurs at run time.

Any clever ideas on how to stop execution on invalid runtime values? Ideally in a way that indicates which line the error occurred on....

The context is that I'm doing math on the extended complex plane which allows infinity, but doesn't permit some operations (such as 0/0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, not using WebGL or any other *graphics* API.
In terms of shaders there are no such things as "runtime errors" there is only "undefined" behavior.

The only way to do runtime feedback is to color code your validations into the backbuffer or textures assuming you're doing the math in a fragment shader. Otherwise you're out of luck and may want to look into the APIs actually made for GPGPU namely OpenCL and Cuda.